# how to use "php include function" if the file from sumbit form?

Tags: php

I understand the include function in php where the directory has been determined, like this:

```
include (dirname (__FILE__). '/file.php');
```

my question: **can I use this function if the file from submit form?**

my source code:

upload.php

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

process.php

```
<?php
include (dirname (__FILE__). '??????????');
?>
```

Bad english, sorry

Comment: You actually want to run a user uploaded file??? Dont do that

Comment: ok if you want this, where you store the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One does not simply run a file uploaded by a user.

That being said, the details of the uploaded files are stored in the [$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array. The temporary name (and path) of the uploaded file is `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`.

You could either `include` this file directly:

```
include $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

Or, you could store this file first, using `move_uploaded_file` and then include that file:

```
$destination = "path/to/file.php";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destination);
include $destination;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this, you can do:

```
include $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

Uploaded files are not put in the same directory as the script, so you don't need `dirname(__FILE)`. The `tmp_name` field contains the full pathname to the uploaded file.